# Keep npm linked folder color in grep on terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, npm-link

I have a folder in `node_modules` which is linked to another project (using `npm link my-plugin`). Let's call it `my-plugin`.

When I run `ls node_modules` I get a list with all folders which contains `my-plugin` of course. The `my-plugin` folder has a different color (to notice me that it linked).

[image]

Now, I have a lot of folders in `node_modules` and I want to get only the certain folder so I'm using `grep`. Something like this:

```
ls node_modules | grep my-plugin
```

The problem is that `grep` painting the expression so I'm missing the linked color of `my-plugin`.

[image]

The problem is that sometimes I run my app with the link and sometimes with the original plugin so I need to know if it linked now or not.

I hope it's clear. If not, let me know.

Comment: Grep just operates on text, it has no way of knowing what the text means. You should use `find` instead if you want to filter by criteria such as "is a link" or not (`find -type l`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colouring of the output of `ls` is determined by the `LS_COLORS` environment variable, which is often set in `.bashrc` by evaluating the output of `dircolors -b`, or using a custom file, as in `dircolors -b "$HOME/.dircolors"`. Mine contains, for example,

```
# Symbolic link
LINK 35
```

which renders links as purple.

Grep, on the other hand, colourizes its output as determined by the `GREP_COLORS` environment variable. It is a string of colon separated capabilities; the default is for my grep is

```
ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36
```

where the important part is `ms=01;31`: it sets

> SGR substring for matching non-empty text in a selected line.

where "SGR" is "Select Graphic Rendition"; `01;31` sets the pattern matched by grep to bold red over the default background.

So, no matter what `LS_COLORS` sets your linked directories to, grep will always use its own colours for matches as it has no way of knowing what the text it is looking at means.

A workaround could be to filter types with `find`:

```
find node-modules -type l -name 'my-plugin'
```

will return matches only if they are links.

Comment: Works good, Thanks (on the answer and the detailed explanation)